# Issue in colab with audio clipping using ffmpeg_extract_subclip

Tags: machine-learning, ffmpeg, google-colaboratory, audio-processing

With all the updated libraries in colab, I am facing the given error. Please help.

Comment: Hello Swaraj,  please update your post to show the code in question and the error message.  It will help people understand why you have a problem and how they can help.

Comment: if os.path.exists(audio_name):
    output_file='file1'+'.webm'
    ffmpeg_extract_subclip(audio_name,ts,te,targetname=files.download(output_file))
    files.download(output_file)
    os.remove(audio_name)